# List from sql statement not filled in managed bean ArrayList

Tags: java, jsf

The Database.java fills a list with results called "results", in the managed bean called CategoryBean.java, i'm trying to implement these results in an arraylist called 'category'. Eventually, this list should be made visible in category.xhtml. Somewhere in this process, there is a mistake in my code. I'm quite new to Java (and couldn't find the solution on another topic) so all help is more than welcome.

Concerning the database, the table 'Categories' has two attributes:
- category_Id (int)
- description (string)

Database.java

```java
public List<Category> getCategories()

                throws SQLException, NamingException {
            List<Category> result = new ArrayList<Category>();
            String sql = "select * from categories order by description";
            Connection connection = null;
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
            ResultSet resultSet = null;

            try {

                connection = getConnection();
                preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    Category category = new Category();
                    category.setCategoryId(
                            resultSet.getInt("category_id"));
                    category.setDescription(
                            resultSet.getString("description"));
                    result.add(category);

                }
            } finally {

                if (resultSet != null && !resultSet.isClosed()) {
                    resultSet.close();
                }
                if (preparedStatement != null
                        && !preparedStatement.isClosed()) {
                    preparedStatement.close();
                }
                if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) {
                    connection.close();
                }

            }

            return result;

        }

    }
```

CategoryBean.java

```java
public class CategoryBean implements Serializable {
        private Database db = new Database();
        private ArrayList<Category> categories;

        public ArrayList<Category> getCategory(){

            if (categories == null) {
                categories = new ArrayList<>();
            }

            try {   
                categories.addAll(db.getCategories());
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return categories;
        }

    }
```

Category.xhtml

```html
<head>
    <title>Categories</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h:outputLabel value="Categories" styleClass="kop" />
    <h:body styleClass="body" />
    <p />
        <h:dataTable value="#{categoriesBean.categories}" var="item">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputLabel value="description" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputLabel value="#{item.description}" />
            </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you get any `Exception`s? If so: please include the stack trace. What data is in your database? Please create a [MRE].

Comment: I've updated my post (first post, wasn't fully aware of the post protocol), I didn't receive any exceptions, the xhtml just loads without the table.

Comment: Looks to me, from the code you posted, that field `categories` in class `CategoryBean` is not populated when this line of your XHTML is processed: `<h:dataTable value="#{categoriesBean.categories}" var="item">`. I think you need to call method `getCategories()` of class `Database` in the constructor of class `CategoryBean`. Apart from that, I think the tag _eclipse_ is not relevant but the tag _jsf_ is.

Comment: If the arraylist is not populated, this is not a jsf thing. Try to narrow things down (the [mcve] thing is btw something that you are 'required' to read when subscribing to SO. It is mentioned in texts. Please read [ask] and [tour] (again?)

Comment: Please read about JPA. It saves you a lot of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Database db = new Database();
    private ArrayList<Category> categories;

    public ArrayList<Category> getCategory(){

        if (categories == null) {
            categories = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        try {   
            categories.addAll(db.getCategories());
```

In the above part, you have declared new Database() but have not set any value in it, you should set the Category objects(with value) into the db object.
for eg.

```
db.setCategories(categoryList) // with values set
```